# asp.net 2.0: Wrong PostBack-Detection

Tags: asp.net, postback

I have installed the ISS 8.0 on a Windows 8 Computer.
The framworks 2.0, 3,5 and 4.0 were already installed on the machine.

I created an new application pool for the .NET-Version 2.0.
Then I created a new web application which was written in ASP.NET 2.0 and assigned this web application to the mentioned application pool.

Everything worked fine until I made a change in the web.config file which caused an error (because of a typing error).

Since this error I have a wrong postback behavior!
When one frame posts its formfields to a second frame, the second frame identifies wrongly a postback!
This behavior makes the second frame useless :(

I had the same problem on a production server from one of my customers.
I only got rid of it by reinstalling the whole machine.

I hope, someone of you knows a better solution for that ;)

Comment: How is it "wrongly identifying" a postback? Please give exact details about what is being sent to the server and how it is being processed (e.g. are you using `Page.IsPostback` or something else?)

Comment: Yes, I use Page.IsPostback.
When I submit from the header frame to the content frame Page.IsPostback is true in the content frame although it isn't a postback :(